# Set a keyboard shortcut for an action in browser

Tags: google-chrome

this might not be the right place for this but I’m trying to create a keyboard shortcut to press the previous button on my udacity.com videos. I’m technically competent to find the element but not much  else. Anyone know how I could learn to do this?  Thanks

Comment: You need JavaScript for this.

Comment: This is unclear. Do you have a website that serves udacity.com videos and you'd like to implement a "Previous" button? Or do you want to be able to use udacity.com's "Previous" button with a hotkey? Or what?

Comment: I'd like to be able to use udacity.com's previous button with a hotkey.

Comment: Then you'll probably be best off with something like AutoHotkey.

Comment: Also, it means that you don't have a single relevant tag.

Comment: thanks. I wasn't sure what direction I'd need to go in

Comment: This question is also either too broad or requesting a library recommendation, neither of which is on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the most commonly used package [pyhk](http://schurpf.com/python/python-hotkey-module/).
The next method is by using [registerhotkey method](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#RegisterHotKey).

In `registerhotkey` method there are two parameters `hotkeyId, modifiers, keycode`.  `hotkeyId` is the id of the key and when the user pres the hot keyid the event triggers and the function executes.

Answer (score 2):

Re: "I'd like to be able to use udacity.com's previous button with a hotkey", Google scared up these keyboard shortcuts:

```
K and spacebar toggle play|pause.
->|L jumps forward 5|10sec.  (arrow keys (and spacebar) require focus to work.)
<-|J jumps backward 5|10sec.
Tab|Shift+Tab to move focus forward|backward between controls.
Home key or 0 to go to video start, # to jump to #0% of the video, e.g., 3 jumps to 30% thru.  End key to jump to end.
Shift+{N|P} for next|previous video in playlist.
<|> keys to {de|in}crease playback speed.  (remember Shift key.)
F toggles full|normal screen.  Esc also brings back normal view.
Arrow up|down to raise|lower volume.  M to mute.
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13029265)

Comment: @NSNoob, the OP is "trying to create a keyboard shortcut to press the previous button on my udacity.com videos" while my answer provides the shortcut: "Shift+{N|P} for next|previous video in playlist"

Comment: oh don't worry about it. It was obviously a wrong review and other reviewers rectified my mistake, seeing as your post is still here